# Is there any way to override the define statement while invoking the toolchain?

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I am working on my own custom CI/CD system for my purposes.
I have projects in IAR 6.5, 7.3 and 8.3 with toolchains 1.40, 3.11 and 7.50 respectively.

In each project there is a file with define statement which configures a hardware to work in a specific way and a purpose of CI - to automate these compilations, so that the programmer does not need to manually overwrite this define (and many other defines) and start compilation manually.

Is there any way to override the define statement while invoking the toolchain without code manipulations ?

**UPD**
I use an IAR toolchain, not a GCC

```
iarbuild.exe my_project.ewp -build pr_name_from_ewp_file -log errors
```

IAR toolchain works with .ewp file and gets all needed files automatically.

Comment: GCC has "-D" option

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show/explain how you invoke the toolchain. Is the file specified in the IAR project as "pre-include", "automatic include" or similar? (I don't remember how it's called.)

Comment: You added the `iarbuild...` command but did not write any details about the "file with define statement". How is this file specified in your IAR project? Is it included explicitly with `#include ...` in a source file? Is it specified in the project configuration?

Comment: @Bodo it's like main.c and main.h and main.h is included with ```#include```
All defines are in main.h
And I have an idea to comment specific defines related to specific settings and provide them through the console.
But I don't know if iarbuild allows this like GCC with -D, going to check it now.

Comment: @AleksandrValentirov Please [edit] your question and **add all requested information to the question**. Please show the contents of the file and explain what you want to change for your CI build. Please also show how the file is included: `#include <file.h>` or `#include "file.h"`. Is the file in the same directory as the source file which includes it? Is it acceptable to run a script that modifies the header file automatically for your CI build? Or to modify the project file?

Comment: [https://www.iar.com/knowledge/support/technical-notes/general/iarbuild.exe-and-preprocessor-defines/](https://www.iar.com/knowledge/support/technical-notes/general/iarbuild.exe-and-preprocessor-defines/)

Comment: @kkrambo thanks a lot. I will check if it is suitable for me to use iccarm, but it sounds great.